# Python pytube module internal explanation. How does a single assignment statement assign other fields to self?

Tags: python, pytube

Please take a look at these pictures, [before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOEVc.png) & [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYVEg.png). I want to know how a single assignment statement `self.watch_url = f"https://youtube.com/watch?v={self.video_id}"` changes self object totally. It's code snippet from the module "pytube".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the thing is that when checking self on IDE debugger, it automatically invokes function with @property, which is the reason why other properties have data.